# How to set image url to Subsampling-Scale-ImageView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, url, imageview

Hello I want to set image url (coming from Firebase storage) to `Subsampling-Scale-ImageView`. Please help me with this, here is my code

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView;
imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(missingPerson.getImageUrl()));
```

Comment: Try using Glide.

Comment: The best option that you have is [Glide for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: This library doesn't support remote images. You have to download it beforehand.

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried using Glide and Picasso but this library needs the images to be downloaded. Do you know any alternative for zooming images?

Comment: @Pawel If you know about any alternative to SubsamplingScaleImageView for zooming images, please do share with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Glide.with(this)<br>
                .asBitmap()<br>
                .load(yourURL)<br>
                .error(R.drawable.error)<br>
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)<br>
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {<br>
                    @Override<br>
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {<br>
                        scaleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(resource));<br>
                        scaleImageView.buildDrawingCache();<br>
                    }<br>
                    @Override<br>
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {<br> }<br>
                });
```